# zend dynamic creating and using tables

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I need to automatically create tables with same structure each month and use a newest one but old tables should be readable. I think to make a table witch will contain names of this tables but how can I use in Zend_Db_Table_Abstract protected $_name of table that I need? I think to make something like

```
<?php 
class Application_Model_DbTable_ads extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

{

    /** Table name */

    protected $_name    = 'ads';


    public function __construct($name){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_name = $name;

    }
}
```

Does Zend has something to manage this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a great idea to do it that way.

Comment: Why you need to create tables with same structure each month.

Comment: I have few applications that use this database and only this one uses Zend

Answer (score 0):

You can create table with prefix of year+month and concatenate table name with current year+month dynamically in code:

```
protected $_name = "table_name_" . date("Y-m");
```

Comment: You want to read from all tables oldest and newest? In this case you can create a merge table and read from there http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html